# How to set datasource when configuring tungsten replication in ubuntu for a mysql database

Tags: tungsten-replicator

I am following this tutorial on seting up fan-in or multi-source replication:
http://datacharmer.blogspot.com/2011/08/usability-improvements-in-tungsten-204.html The main problem is in setting the datasource in this step --datasource=qa_r4_continuent_com

I know that the datasource is different from the database name, but how do I view it for the mysql database I am using. Was it automatically created, since research tells me that it is used when executing queries on a database. If so, how do I view the datasource in ubuntu?

If it is not automatically created, how do I set it or how do I create it? Could you please post a step by step tutorial or provide a reliable link to a tutorial that shows me how to resolve this problem.

Rumbi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasource is automatically created for you. There is no need to configure any jdbc or odbc connections. The datasource is found in release directory/tungsten.cfg after starting the tungsten replicator. The naming convention chosen by continuent is my_network_com so that if your network address is 192.168.56.100, your datasource is 192_168_56_100.

Happy hacking!!!